# Email author, committer and another specified email address in Travis

Tags: travis-ci

I'm having trouble understanding if this is even possible from the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications)

I want to configure travis so that the author and committer are notified of any build failures. But I also want to notify a specific email address at all times, regardless if they are the author or not.

From what I understand, adding the following to `.travis.yml` removes the emailing the committer and author:

```
notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - someone@example.com
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
```

Is what I'm looking for possible, and If so what do I need to specify in `notifications`?

Comment: Can you test if you can expand environment variables there? You could set those to some `git log` magic's output.

Comment: I too wish this was possible, so I opened an issue for it on GitHub, referencing your question: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8868
Let's hope the developers add this option someday.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications#How-is-the-build-email-receiver-determined%3F:

> If there’s a setting specified, Travis CI only sends an emails to the addresses specified there, rather than to the committer and author.